# Spark submit application not logging as defined by log4j properties given to spark workers and master

Tags: apache-spark, log4j

We have Spark running in cluster mode with Spark standalone cluster manager with 1 master and 10 workers. Recently I managed to set up central logging to master using rsyslog which would gather all worker logs onto master for easier debugging and monitoring. Turns out this is not working as expected, I just noticed that we're missing logs such as `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. And generally it seems like the logs of application we submit to Spark are missing from worker logs and my assumption is that they're logged separately, but I'm not able to find much about Spark logging details online.

This is our worker log4j properties file built on top of default Spark log4j properties file:

```
log.level=INFO
log.active.appenders=SYSLOG

log4j.rootLogger=${log.level}, ${log.active.appenders}

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n

log4j.appender.SYSLOG=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.threshold=${log.level}
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.syslogHost=localhost:514
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.conversionPattern=spark/worker %d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n

# Set the default spark-shell log level to WARN. When running the spark-shell, the
# log level for this class is used to overwrite the root logger's log level, so that
# the user can have different defaults for the shell and regular Spark apps.
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.Main=WARN

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.sparkproject.jetty=WARN
log4j.logger.org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.parquet=ERROR
log4j.logger.parquet=ERROR

# SPARK-9183: Settings to avoid annoying messages when looking up nonexistent UDFs in SparkSQL with Hive support
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler=FATAL
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry=ERROR

# skipping kafka poling logs in structure streamig
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution=WARN

# all 'hr' logs
log4j.logger.hr=${log.hr.level}
```

And this file is provided to Spark worker inside of environment variable inside of service file because we're running workers as systemd services, like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Spark worker
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
Environment=SPARK_CONF_DIR=/etc/user/spark
Environment=SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS="-Dlog.file=spark-worker.log -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///etc/user/spark/worker.log4j.properties"
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/spark/current
ExecStart=/home/user/spark/current/sbin/start-slave.sh spark://host:7077

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

By trying and failing I realized that file is consumed and provided to worker node because it did stop writing to a local file when I disabled it and `log4j.properties` configuration is not rocket science so I suspect that submitted application may log in some other way, or needs a separate file. The issue is not with rsyslog configuration either because the logs are written to central log file, but it seems like worker are only logging startup and shutdown, nothing in between and I suppose it shouldn't be like that. One of the basic logs I expect is Kafka consumer properties, but that's not happening.

Is my configuration wrong or there is more to Spark logging setup in case of using `spark-submit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue by adding log4j properties file in `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` and `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` as VM option `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///etc/user/spark/master.log4j.properties`. Seems like spark does not forward it's log4j properties file to application that is submitted with `spark-submit`, the application requires it's own log4j properties file reference.